# How to scroll dynamically content of a JSON array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ticker

I have a JSON object which store data about a website RSS feed:

```
var varNameSpace = <?php echo json_encode($article); ?>;
```

and I'm on the way to develop a Ticker, I need to display all objects elements on `<li>` tags and add the effect of scrolling dynamically. 
Before I have used a javascript function to do that scrolling my javascript function look like:

```
<script>
var boutton=document.getElementById("start");
function startTicker(){
$("#news li:first").slideUp(function(){
$(this).appendTo($("#news")).slideDown();
});
}
boutton.onclick=setInterval(startTicker, 3000);
</script>
```

my HTML page look like:

```
<div>
<?php
foreach(getFeed() as $article){
?>

<ul id="news">
<li><h3><a href="<?php echo $article['link'] ?>"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></a></h3></li>
</ul>
<p>
<?php echo $article['description'];  ?>
</p>                
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Once I execute this page, it was just the first element of the list which scroll the other list elements was considered as a unique element. 
So, how can i scroll over all the list elements ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but I suspect the `li:first` has something to do with only selecting the first element.

No need to reinvent the wheel with this though, there are some great plugins out there that can achieve what you're asking for with minimal effort.

One such example that I've used before is http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/

It was quite easy to implement, and as you're already using jQuery won't require you to load any additional libraries.

On the other hand, if you're set on writing your own, this CodePen by Noel Killebrew looks like it would be a good starting point https://codepen.io/noelietrex/pen/ZGGoZM

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is on the javascript function, I need something to loop over all the displayed `<li>` elements with javascript, because the <li> element used on the javascript function is static

Comment: The scenario is as follow:
1- data is fetched from the RSS feed and I put it on an array (title, description, link, date)
2- the php function foreach is used to loop the array and display all the elements on <li> element
so when I use the jaascript function its the last element <li> that was got a not all the elements